# How to create an in-memory database with SQL CE 4.0?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

**Question**

How do I create an in-memory database with SQL CE 4.0?

**Context**

I'd like to do some unit testing (or automated integration testing) with a real database, however, one that is in-memory. That'll make the tests run fast, plus, the database will vanish in thin air once the test are finished running.

According to Scott Guthrie's blog post "[VS 2010 SP1 and SQL CE](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx)" the new SQL CE 4.0 is capable of doing just that: providing an in-memory database.

However, I couldn't find any tutorials or code examples on the web showing how it is done. I only found this connection string example in this [blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4). But that also hits the harddrive.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server CE 4.0 does not allow for memory-only databases.

That blog posts says that CE runs in-memory of your application.

A comment by Scott says that CE maps the file into memory, but that still requires the file.

Comment: I agree.  And you can reference my post for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

> @linkgoron,
>
> > Are you considering adding a in memory DB feature?  This can help a
> >     lot with unit testing (Create/Drop a
> >     in memory DB using Code-First for
> >     every test) which should be much
> >     faster than a file based DB (I've used
> >     this approach with other DBs, and
> >     would love to actually use SQL Server
> >     CE for it).  This also reduces the
> >     need to mock the Data
> >     access/Repository when unit testing.
>
> SQL CE itself runs in-memory - and so
>   is quite fast to create and use for
>   unit test projects.  I believe it does
>   require the DB file on disk - but
>   immediately maps it in to memory (so
>   it as fast as in-memory).  You would
>   still create/delete the file as part
>   of your setup/teardown logic - but
>   this should be as easy as deleting the
>   file (there is no explicit drop or
>   cleanup required).
>
> Hope this helps,
>
> Scott

~ From the linked blog post.