# Is it possible to run SQL Server Compact Edition totally in memory?

Tags: sql-server, in-memory-database, compact-database

I have a need to run a small database in memory (no disk). It's important that the data only be loaded in memory and not persisted on disk. I will load the database up when the application starts. The source database is SQL Server. Its a very small configuration database that I want to copy from the source into a memory-only database. I'm thinking SQL Server Compact edition might be a good fit here, but am not sure if that will write data to disk or if it can be configured to only run in memory. Hoping someone can shed some light on that.

Also, I realize there is a pagefile that will be on disk. However my main concern is data at rest. This means I don't want the database to be permanently stored on disk.

Comment: Keep in mind that Windows will write it to disk if it needs the memory freed up for other uses (pagefile).

Comment: Why don't you want it written to disk? What about the pagefile? Why not instead use an in-memory data structure within your application?

Comment: I know - and figured someone would make that comment :-) This is more about not storing the data on disk permanently, as opposed to in a pagefile, etc.

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085410/how-to-create-an-in-memory-database-with-sql-ce-4-0

Comment: @JiggsJedi - good find - that seems to suggest that CE actually does create a file on disk, but then immediately loads it into memory. That's not quite what I was hoping to hear. I really just want a memory only DB, so I might have to look at other non-CE memory only DBs.

Comment: JJOC - how would you handle an app crash if its entirely in memory?

Comment: Install a RAMDisk driver, configure the database to put its files there, and set up the RAMDisk to not persist contents across reboots? If that won't work, I question whether you've selected the right tool (SQL Server CE) for the task in the first place.

Comment: @JiggsJedi re "how would you handle app crash" - I would just load up the database form the source at application start up. Also as the source database is updated, the updates are pushed to the in memory databases.

Comment: [This link](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html) says about SO sql database "SQL Server Cache. The entire database is cached in-memory. The entire thing." I wonder how they do that.